# Powershell DNS forward lookup zone list then check

Tags: powershell, dns

Ok so we are migrating to a new NS for all of our external domains. The current one has plenty of domains that are no longer valid but have not been removed. I am attempting to export a list of all forward lookup zones in DNS, ping them to see if they are alive and sort too two different files so i can recheck the bad names manually.

First need to export to a file so it can be moved to a different location for testing.

**Export**

```
dnscmd /enumzones /Forward | out-file C:\temp\zones.txt
```

**Test**

```
$names = Get-Content "C:\temp\zones.txt"
foreach ($name in $names){
  if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $name -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
    Add-Content c:\temp\resolved.csv "$name,up"
  }
  else{
    Add-Content C:\temp\unresolved.csv "$name,down"
  }
}
```

**Problem** 
The export command writes a value with extra information. 
I.E.

```
Enumerated zone list:
    Zone count = 673

 Zone name                 Type       Storage         Properties

 .                         Cache      File            
 domain1.com.au            Primary    File            
 domain2.co.nz             Primary    File            
 domain3.com.au            Primary    File
```

No problem with just clearing out the top of the file etc, but how can I format the zone list output so the powershell can read it?

**Answer**
Answer for Server 2012 marked below by @sodawillow, I had to teak a little for 2008R2, but couldn't of done it with out his answer.
I also messed with it a little as i was having issues with none of the names resolving due to white space from export.

```
#store forward lookup zones names in an array
$zoneNames = Get-WmiObject -Namespace Root\MicrosoftDNS -Class "MicrosoftDNS_Zone" | ? { $_.ContainerName -Notlike '..RootHints' -And $_.ContainerName -NotLike '..Cache' -And !$_.Reverse } | Select Name

#declare results arrays and files paths
$resolvedZones = @()
$unresolvedZones = @()
$resolvedFile = "C:\Temp\resolved.csv"
$unresolvedFile = "C:\Temp\unresolved.csv"

#for each zone name
foreach ($zoneName in $zoneNames){
$string = $zoneName.Substring(0)
$string = $string.Trim()


    #if it responds to ping
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName "$string" -Count 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {

        #build result object and add it to resolved zones array
        $resolvedZones += [PSCustomObject]@{ ZoneName = $zoneName; Status = "UP" }
    } else {

        #build result object and add it to unresolved zones array
        $unresolvedZones += [PSCustomObject]@{ ZoneName = $zoneName; Status = "DOWN" }
    }
}

#export results arrays as CSV in results files (if not empty)
if($unresolvedZones.Length -gt 0) { $unresolvedZones | Export-Csv $unresolvedFile -NoTypeInformation }
if($resolvedZones.Length -gt 0) { $resolvedZones | Export-Csv $resolvedFile -NoTypeInformation }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note : I have mixed *forward* and *reverse* in my answer, but it
>   demonstrates how you can retrieve and re-use DNS zone names.

There is an appropriate PowerShell cmdlet to list DNS zones, `Get-DNSServerZone`.

Here is an adapted script :

```
#store reverse lookup zones names in an array
$zoneNames = (Get-DnsServerZone | Where-Object { $_.IsReverseLookupZone -eq $true }).ZoneName

#declare results arrays and files paths
$resolvedZones = @()
$unresolvedZones = @()
$resolvedFile = "C:\Temp\resolved.csv"
$unresolvedFile = "C:\Temp\unresolved.csv"

#for each zone name
foreach ($zoneName in $zoneNames){

    #if it responds to ping
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $zoneName -Count 2 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {

        #build result object and add it to resolved zones array
        $resolvedZones += [PSCustomObject]@{ ZoneName = $zoneName; Status = "UP" }
    } else {

        #build result object and add it to unresolved zones array
        $unresolvedZones += [PSCustomObject]@{ ZoneName = $zoneName; Status = "DOWN" }
    }
}

#export results arrays as CSV in results files (if not empty)
if($unresolvedZones.Length -gt 0) { $unresolvedZones | Export-Csv $unresolvedFile -NoTypeInformation }
if($resolvedZones.Length -gt 0) { $resolvedZones | Export-Csv $resolvedFile -NoTypeInformation }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i forgot to mention i was using Server 2008R2, so i will have to tweak it but yours looks amazing.

Comment: I mixed *reverse* and *forward* in my answer, sorry about that. I was about to post something about the WMI request when I read your edit, glad you found out how to adapt this :).